# Are heal on hit also applied on dot effects?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

In Diablo 3, I wonder if my life on hit also heals me on DOT effects. More specifically, I have a Barbarian with a certain amount of heal per hit. If I were to use the Rend spell (AOE DOT around me), would every damage tick, heal me for the full amount which is displayed in character details screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOTs return the life per hit amount ONLY on the initial hit, if we take rend here as an example, you gain your Life per Hit x the Proc coefficient(I'll come later to that) per enemy hit with the initial use of Rend.

If you use a rune which makes a DOT spread, like Bloodbath in the Rend example, you again gain the Life per Hit x Proc Coefficient per enemy spreaded to.

You don't gain the Life if you Hit enemies who are immune to damage (shielding).

Proc coefficients for all abilities are listed [**HERE**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AgL5S3Revw9ddEhScEpSLWhnRDZKV25OaWZJcHdkN0E&f=true&noheader=true&gid=1)

Sources: Own Experience, [**SOURCE 1**](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271499223) [**SOURCE 2**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11914351645)