# Knockback on Hit with Witch Doctor

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I have a Rare Ceremonial Knife (Witch Doctor) with 2.0% Chance to Knockback on Hit. Is this effect triggered by non-melee attacks, such as Firebomb and Firebats? I have not seen any evidence in-game that the effect is triggering when using these two skills.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, every source of damage can potentially trigger a on-hit effect.
Look [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71974/how-do-on-hit-effects-work-with-channeled-dot-skills), as it was already answered, for more info.

Comment: I read that answer before posting my question. As I am not seeing any in-game animation of the Knockback ever, I am unsure that this "on hit" effect is triggered by non-melee attacks.

Comment: Some enemies are heavy and some are even immune to knockback. It's almost impossible to tell on some enemies.

Comment: Also this chance for knockback on hit scaled with proc coefficents, you can read more about them here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166328/are-heal-on-hit-also-applied-on-dot-effects/166332#166332